# Travelling time of data through TCP/IP stack (Linux)

Tags: linux, performance, tcp, tcpdump, network-monitoring

I want to know how much time occurs from the moment I call

```
res.send("Hello,World")
```

in my NodeJS application till the moment IP package leaves NIC card.
Is there a way to do this?

Why do I want to know that?

I have a server on CentOS6 serving 400 req/s. My partner who generates the requests measures my response time. Recently the request rate has increased to 800 req/s and the partner detected increase in my response time. The time from the moment my app gets request till it issues `res.send()` has not changed. Therefore, the hypothesis is that Linux TCP/IP stack has slowed. I want to check this hypothesis by actually observing the time needed by TCP/IP stack to process my response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `res.send()` has been called the package *has* left the NIC. What you are interested in is the time `send()` takes.